# Not showing TEST ads and REAL add Rewarded Video by Admob for Android

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I am facing an error from last week, please help me better.
I implement `RewardedVideo` by `Admob` but I am getting `error 3` and some time `error 0`.this both error facing me when I try both `test ads` and `real ads`.

**My Code is below**.

```
private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
Button adsShow;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

    loadRewardedVideoAd();
    adsShow=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mainidads);
    adsShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()){
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
            }
        }
    });

}
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {

    if(!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {

        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + rewardItem.getType() + "  amount: " +
            rewardItem.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {

}
```

my Dependency on **build.gradle** is

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
}
```

My Log for

```
'  07-31 18:02:14.123 2526-3085/info.burhanisolution.dholkaapp W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/info.burhanisolution.dholkaapp/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory 07-31 18:02:14.967 2526-3008/info.burhanisolution.dholkaapp W/Ads: Fail to instantiate adapter com.google.DummyAdapter
android.os.RemoteException
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbp(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbo(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbm(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxo.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzek.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
    at mt.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):10)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):5)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):15)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.j.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):27)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):4)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

07-31 18:02:14.968 2526-2526/info.burhanisolution.dholkaapp W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3    '

Kinly please help me.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason you are getting error is you are initializing your ad with add unit ID instead of app ID.

```
// Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
```

reference - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#initialize_mobileads

Change code to reflect correct app_id which is located in ( Admob Console -> App->App Settings->App ID )

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
```

If this doesn't solve your problem please update your question with error log

Comment: Brother i try whole things, do app id in initialize and also try ad unit id in but always return error 3. and when i put my ap id in ad unit id then it return 0. i do all changes test ads ids and real ids, i can't understands what problem here

Comment: please add addTestDevice to your code for your specific device and capture and update your question with logs

Comment: i upload log on my question, please check and reply thanks

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/65 - If you are running it on simulator it will not work... o.w. if you have updated correct app ID code looks good

Comment: i run in my device, i try test device and without test id, but it will not showing video and return error 3, kinly please help me about this, i also re coding but not work.